# How to see how many values are counted in group at certain day of life in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, presto, trino

I have a dataframe:

```
day            id        value
1               a1       right 
2               a1       right 
2               a1       right 
2               a1       right  
3               a1       right 
4               a1       right 
1               b2       right 
1               b2       right 
2               b2       right 
3               b2       right
```

I want to count how many rows there were counted in sum at day 3 for each id group. So desired result is:

```
day            id       count
3               a1       5 
3               b2       4
```

How to do that? I know that in my query I have to write GROUP BY id. But how to count rows in sum at certain day?

Comment: `where day = 3 group by id` maybe

Comment: expected result looks like count from day 1 to day 3

Comment: @ProGu yeah that's right

Answer (score 1):

This might work

```
SELECT MAX(day) day, id, COUNT(*) counts
FROM dataframe
WHERE day <= 3
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: why <= 3? why not == 3

Comment: you need to count from day 1 to day 3, `day = 3` reads rows for day 3 only, not day 1,day 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
select '3' as "Day",id, count(value)
from dataset
where day
group by 2
```